# Get last occurrence of matched csv column when using fgetcsv

Tags: php, fgetcsv

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($data[0] == "var") {
    }
}
```

I'm currently using `fgetcsv` to read a csv file (`$handle`) and return the row where the first column matches `var`. So far this is working well as `$data[0]` are unique values.

But going forward, there may be duplicate values in `$data[0]`, how can I only return the **last** occurrence if there are duplicates?

Comment: Depends on what's in the `if`. If you assign `$data` to something and don't break out of the loop then it will always be the last one.

Comment: @felippe I'm just echoing the other columns in the if .. if ($data[0] == "var") {echo '<div class="buttonno"><a href="' . $data[5] . '" class="button buttonnoo"  target="_blank" data-wiggle style="background-color:' . $data[3] . ';color:' . $data[4] . ';">' . $data[2] . '</a></div>';} But it's returning the first row occurence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the *first* occurrence if there are multiples, as it will `break` out of the loop after the first is found:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($data[0] == "var") {
        $result = $data;
        break; // break out of the loop after the first is found
    }
}
print_r($result): // first one
```

This will get the *last* occurrence, as it will not `break` out of the loop and the last occurrence will be the last one assigned to the result:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($data[0] == "var") {
        $result = $data;
        // loop keeps going until end of file
    }
}
print_r($result): // last one
```

You don't actually need to assign to `$result` as `$data` will contain the proper row after the `break` or after the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just save row somewhere:

```php
$lastRow = null;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($data[0] == "var") {
        $lastRow = $data;
    }
}
```

Every occurrence of wanted row will override the `lastRow` variable so when the loop finish you will have there last row matching your criteria.